# Mapping hibernate table entities through java configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

How do we map hibernate table resources when we are configuring through java instead of xml config files - appreciate help.

xml-mapping for hibernate resource:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
          <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
             <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
         </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
               <value>/config/Stock.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

Java-mapping?

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-sql.properties" })
@ComponentScan({......."})
public class PersistenceConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {...... });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
     (HOW DO WE INTRODUCE mappingResources HERE?)
      return sessionFactory;
   }
```

Comment: Did you find the configuration ? with MappingResources -> List of value, not annotated version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @Entity on the model object solved the problem.
The xml configuration option had not needed this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your configuration at runtime like this:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
    .addResource("Item.hbm.xml")
    .addResource("Bid.hbm.xml");
```

or for class like this:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
    .addClass(org.hibernate.auction.Item.class)
    .addClass(org.hibernate.auction.Bid.class);
```

[reference here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic)

Comment: Am not using xml.I load context as - AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = 
      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
  ctx.register(PersistenceConfig.class);
  ctx.refresh();

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal working Hibernate+JPA setup you are interested in:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DaoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.USER, "sa");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.PASS, "");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, "30");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
        properties.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateEntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        Ejb3Configuration config = new Ejb3Configuration();
        return (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) config.addProperties(hibernateProperties()).
                addAnnotatedClass(User.class).
                buildEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory().getSessionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

}
```